# Reachability.m - File not found - Odd behavior

Tags: ios, import, reachability

I have two files which are of relevance:
CollectionViewController.m and ImageDetailViewController.m

For CollectionViewController.m, the "#import "Reachability.m" + functionality works just fine. I have added all Frameworks as well.

However, when trying to import the Reachability.m file in my ImageDetailViewController.m as well, I get the "Reachability.m - File Not Found"-error. I don't understand why this is happening. Both files are in the same group, folder everything.

[image: CollectionViewController.m]
[image: ImageDetailViewController.m]

Has anyone come across this? I'd appreciate a solution, this is driving me Crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally don't import `Reachability.m`, only required files to be imported are having `.h` extensions called header files. Problem with importing `.m` files would be that compiler might not be able to find the .m file and would complain.

I would recommend you to use forward declarations its quite faster way of building your code and indexing it, You can add the class like this in your code

**CollectionViewController.h**

`@class Reachability;`  in your `CollectionViewController.h` Header file

```
 @property(strong,nonatomic)Reachability *reachability; // here you are declaring a property
```

**CollectionViewController.m**

```
`#import "Reachability.h"` //only .h file is required to be imported
```

now you can use the `reachability` property in your class by `self.reachability`

Comment: well. importing reachability.m allows the app to compile & run fine. using import reachability.h, it won't compile.

Comment: Point is that you use forward declaration in your header files and then import the .h in your implementation file.

Comment: Well if you really want to import .m file then make sure you keep them in the same folder where you importing them, but i would still say this is not the right approach to use importing .m files.

Comment: this did in fact solve the problem, but it still keeps me wondering, why the second view controller can't import the file, when it's actually there (and working for another). still: thanks a lot.